# Optimize JOIN SQL query with additional SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I need a query which will select **just one** (`GROUP BY phi.id_product`) image for each product and this image have to be the one with the **highest priority** (inner `SELECT` with `ORDER BY` statement).

The priority is stored in N:M relation table called `product_has_image`

I've created a query, but it tooks about 3 seconds to execute and I need to optimize it. Here it is:

```
SELECT p.*, i.id AS imageid
FROM `product` p JOIN `category` c on c.`id` = p.`id_category` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id_product, id_image FROM
`product_has_image` ORDER BY priority DESC) phi ON p.id = phi.id_product
LEFT OUTER JOIN `image` i ON phi.id_image = i.id
WHERE (c.`id_parent` = 2 OR c.`id` = 2)
GROUP BY phi.id_product
```

Indexes which I find to be important in this query are:

```
image (PRIMARY id)
product_has_image (PRIMARY id_product, id_image; INDEX id_product; INDEX id_image)
product (PRIMARY id, id_category; INDEX id_category)
category (PRIMARY id; INDEX id_parent)
```

Most of the time takes joining the tables using the SELECT statement which is required for sorting.

Joining with `LEFT JOIN [product_has_image] phi ON p.id = phi.id_product` is much faster, but doesn't assign the image with the highest priority.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. After creating the view it takes about 0.3 - 0.5 seconds on my machine and it's even faster on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatted for sensibility . . .

```
SELECT p.*, i.id AS imageid
FROM `product` p 
INNER JOIN `category` c on (c.`id` = p.`id_category`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id_product, id_image 
                 FROM `product_has_image` 
                 ORDER BY priority DESC) phi 
             ON (p.id = phi.id_product)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `image` i 
             ON (phi.id_image = i.id)
WHERE (c.`id_parent` = 2 OR c.`id` = 2)
GROUP BY phi.id_product
```

Without seeing an execution plan or DDL, I'd guess (shudder) that the problem is likely to be the inner select/sort. If you create a view

```
create view highest_priority_images as
select id_product, max(priority)
from product_has_image
group by id_product
```

Then you can replace that inner SELECT...ORDER BY with a SELECT...INNER JOIN on that view. That would reduce the cardinality, so I'd expect it to run faster.

Posting DDL would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to do it like this:

```
SELECT p.*, i.id AS imageid
FROM `product` p
  INNER JOIN `category` c ON c.id = p.id_category

  /* a list of `id_product`s with their highest priorities
     from `product_has_image` */
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id_product, MAX(priority) AS max_priority
    FROM `product_has_image`
    GROUP BY id_product
  ) m ON p.id = m.id_product

  /* now joining `product_has_image` again, using
     m.`max_priority` for additional filtering */
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_has_image` phi
    ON p.id = phi.id_product AND m.max_priority = phi.priority

  /* if you only select `id` from `image`, you can use
     phi.`id_image` instead and remove this join */
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `image` i ON phi.id_image = i.id

WHERE c.id_parent = 2 OR c.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it now, but wouldn't it be possible to do this?

```
SELECT p.*, i.id AS imageid
FROM `product` p JOIN `category` c on c.`id` = p.`id_category` 
LEFT JOIN `product_has_image` phi ON p.id = phi.id_product
LEFT OUTER JOIN `image` i ON phi.id_image = i.id
WHERE (c.`id_parent` = 2 OR c.`id` = 2)
GROUP BY phi.id_product
ORDER BY phi.priority DESC
```

Do it in a regular join and order by phi.priority.